# Portal users cannot own partner accounts with Customer community plus License

Tags: customer-community

We have 2 profile for eg. ABC and XYZ which are of Customer community plus License. I want to create a contact from a custom object[It has a lookup to contact] from profile ABC using standard oob functionality in the community template - Customer Account Portal Template.

Error - "Portal users cannot own partner accounts"

I am getting this error. Is there any way to avoid it.

I have also tried to change the owner of the contact as below from process builder.
[image]

Please suggest what I am missing here.

Comment: Seems you have missed to mention the error that you are receiving. Please [edit your question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/247170/edit) to provide the exact error.

Comment: Added the error.

Comment: My req. is - 
1. After the creation of contact from a community profile without [Account name].{Because with partner Account it is throwing above error}
2. I tried to set the account name as 'alpha' and Contact Owner to system admin. I got the below error - 
ERROR - "You cannot assign a Portal Account or Contact to a Portal user". Please choose a different user.
3. So, I tried to first Change the contact ownership - and then set same account name to 'Alpha' and it worked.
4. When I open this contact in classic, I enable this contact as a community user and set the profile as 'Beta'.